# long table not going to next page

Tags: longtable

Im trying to get the longtable to work, however it just doesnt go to the next page. Console reads Float too large for page by 369.37903pt. Any idea why its not working?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,accents}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{table}\centering\fontsize{8.8pt}{9.5pt}\selectfont\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Regression von Vermögen und Wohneigentum}
\begin{longtable}{l*{4}{c}}

\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Gesamtvermögen}         &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Wohneigentumskapital}       \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Modell (1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Modell (2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Modell( 3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Modell (4)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mit        Interaktion}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Ohne Interaktion }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mit Interaktion}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Ohne Interaktion}\\
            \\
[1em]
\hline
\\
[1em]
\textbf{A - Haupteffekte}
\\
[1em]
\\
Dummy Ethnie, 0 = Weiß      &           0         &           0         &           0         &           0         \\
            &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Ethnie, 1 = Schwarz      &    -36319.1\sym{**} &    -56016.4\sym{***}&    -15288.3\sym{***}&    -26935.2\sym{***}\\
            &     (-2.90)         &     (-7.99)         &     (-9.99)         &    (-22.55)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Region, 0 = Süden    &           0         &           0         &           0         &           0         \\
            &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Region, 1 = Nordosten    &     15888.9         &      2391.8         &     41757.4\sym{***}&     32229.1\sym{***}\\
            &      (1.53)         &      (0.17)         &     (16.49)         &     (14.89)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Region, 2 = Norden    &       384.2         &       722.8         &     -3906.0\sym{***}&     -5185.5\sym{***}\\
            &      (0.04)         &      (0.08)         &     (-3.41)         &     (-5.28)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Region, 3 = Westen    &    182944.9\sym{***}&    169367.0\sym{***}&     52579.7\sym{***}&     47948.8\sym{***}\\
            &     (18.26)         &      (9.56)         &     (22.57)         &     (21.84)         \\
[2em]
\textbf{B - Interaktionseffekte}
\\
[1em]
Weiße im Süden&           0         &                     &           0         &                     \\
            &         (.)         &                     &         (.)         &                     \\
[1em]
Schwarze im Nordosten&    -77732.2\sym{**} &                     &    -57043.6\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (-3.12)         &                     &    (-18.70)         &                     \\
[1em]
Schwarze im Norden&     30053.3         &                     &      4866.4\sym{**} &                     \\
            &      (1.33)         &                     &      (2.68)         &                     \\
[1em]
Schwarze im Westen&   -141388.1\sym{***}&                     &    -33609.6\sym{***}&                     \\
            &     (-4.45)         &                     &     (-8.79)         &                     \\
[2em]
\textbf{C - Kontrollvariablen}
 \\
[1em]
Dummy Geschlecht, 1 = Frau  &    -46099.2\sym{***}&    -45859.0\sym{***}&     -4576.7         &     -4535.3         \\
            &     (-4.38)         &     (-4.53)         &     (-1.91)         &     (-1.90)         \\
[1em]
Alter       &      7313.8\sym{***}&      7300.6\sym{***}&      2117.3\sym{***}&      2114.7\sym{***}\\
            &     (37.17)         &     (14.92)         &     (15.89)         &     (15.95)         \\
[1em]
Familiengesamteinkommen&       3.714\sym{***}&       3.715\sym{***}&       0.421\sym{***}&       0.421\sym{***}\\
            &    (107.93)         &     (10.00)         &      (9.52)         &      (9.52)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Studienabschluss, 1 = Ja&     70655.0\sym{***}&     70536.8\sym{***}&     27245.3\sym{***}&     27099.5\sym{***}\\
            &      (9.59)         &      (4.59)         &     (10.70)         &     (10.64)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Highschoolabschluss, 1 = Ja&     60822.9\sym{***}&     59950.4\sym{***}&     12746.3\sym{***}&     12764.6\sym{***}\\
            &      (6.46)         &      (8.06)         &      (9.94)         &      (9.96)         \\
[1em]
Dummy Heirat, 1 = Verheiratet &    -72404.1\sym{***}&    -72931.2\sym{***}&      4325.7         &      3908.1         \\
            &     (-6.89)         &     (-3.96)         &      (1.24)         &      (1.12)         \\
[1em]
Hypothek    &    -0.00455\sym{*}  &    -0.00458         &   -0.000785\sym{**} &   -0.000784\sym{**} \\
            &     (-2.00)         &     (-1.92)         &     (-2.68)         &     (-2.67)         \\
[1em]
2.Hypothek  &     -0.0170\sym{**} &     -0.0170\sym{***}&    -0.00316\sym{**} &    -0.00320\sym{**} \\
            &     (-2.68)         &     (-4.81)         &     (-2.95)         &     (-2.99)         \\
[1em]
Anzahl an Kindern&    -46047.5\sym{***}&    -45879.9\sym{***}&     -9327.4\sym{***}&     -9249.5\sym{***}\\
            &    (-14.08)         &     (-9.74)         &     (-9.46)         &     (-9.39)         \\
[1em]
Kinderbetreuung&      -12.77\sym{***}&      -12.81\sym{***}&       2.249         &       2.239         \\
            &     (-7.26)         &     (-3.30)         &      (1.91)         &      (1.90)         \\
[1em]
Ausgaben für Gesundheitsversorgung&       10.33\sym{***}&       10.30\sym{***}&       0.602\sym{**} &       0.595\sym{**} \\
            &     (16.89)         &      (5.64)         &      (2.99)         &      (2.94)         \\
[1em]
Wohnausgaben  &       2.291\sym{***}&       2.293\sym{**} &       1.093\sym{***}&       1.095\sym{***}\\
            &     (10.06)         &      (2.89)         &      (6.05)         &      (6.05)         \\
[1em]

Energieausgaben&       51.06\sym{***}&       51.52\sym{***}&       16.99\sym{***}&       17.17\sym{***}\\
            &     (25.68)         &      (5.93)         &      (9.42)         &      (9.51)         \\
[1em]
Transportausgaben&       2.353\sym{***}&       2.329\sym{*}  &       0.374\sym{*}  &       0.372\sym{*}  \\
            &      (6.62)         &      (2.04)         &      (2.56)         &      (2.54)         \\
[1em]
Bildungsausgaben&      -0.682         &      -0.634         &       1.433\sym{***}&       1.466\sym{***}\\
            &     (-1.44)         &     (-0.36)         &      (5.16)         &      (5.26)         \\
[1em]
Erbschaft   &      0.0500\sym{***}&      0.0499\sym{*}  &     0.00581         &     0.00575         \\
            &      (5.42)         &      (2.08)         &      (1.66)         &      (1.63)         \\
[2em]
\textbf{D - Feste Zeiteffekte}
 \\
[1em] 
1999   &           0         &           0         &           0         &           0         \\
            &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         \\
[1em]
2001   &    -40459.6\sym{**} &    -40525.8\sym{**} &     -1234.0         &     -1254.4         \\
            &     (-2.81)         &     (-2.93)         &     (-0.77)         &     (-0.78)         \\
[1em]
2003   &    -22684.1         &    -22896.4         &      8485.5\sym{***}&      8452.9\sym{***}\\
            &     (-1.57)         &     (-1.61)         &      (4.97)         &      (4.95)         \\
[1em]
2005   &     -7253.0         &     -7289.6         &     22212.4\sym{***}&     22147.4\sym{***}\\
            &     (-0.50)         &     (-0.46)         &      (9.24)         &      (9.20)         \\
[1em]
2007   &     -4361.3         &     -4229.2         &     23984.7\sym{***}&     23970.2\sym{***}\\
            &     (-0.30)         &     (-0.22)         &      (8.70)         &      (8.68)         \\
[1em]
2009   &    -35598.6\sym{*}  &    -35542.6         &     -5367.1         &     -5434.4         \\
            &     (-2.40)         &     (-1.06)         &     (-1.93)         &     (-1.95)         \\
[1em]
2011   &    -96898.3\sym{***}&    -96931.9\sym{***}&    -14559.3\sym{***}&    -14648.2\sym{***}\\
            &     (-6.52)         &     (-5.72)         &     (-5.38)         &     (-5.41)         \\
[1em]
2013   &   -117516.4\sym{***}&   -117580.0\sym{***}&    -14500.6\sym{***}&    -14627.4\sym{***}\\
            &     (-7.75)         &     (-6.67)         &     (-4.95)         &     (-4.99)         \\
[1em]
2015   &    -79309.8\sym{***}&    -79654.7\sym{***}&     -6768.5\sym{*}  &     -7022.1\sym{*}  \\
            &     (-5.25)         &     (-3.82)         &     (-2.21)         &     (-2.29)         \\
[1em]
2017   &    -60464.9\sym{***}&    -60838.3\sym{**} &      4866.0         &      4608.6         \\
            &     (-3.92)         &     (-3.10)         &      (1.41)         &      (1.34)         \\
[1em]
2019   &    -69391.4\sym{***}&    -69735.0\sym{***}&      9985.3\sym{**} &      9680.8\sym{**} \\
            &     (-4.55)         &     (-3.58)         &      (2.72)         &      (2.64)         \\
[2em]
Konstante   &   -462159.6\sym{***}&   -456422.2\sym{***}&   -140031.1\sym{***}&   -136998.7\sym{***}\\
            &    (-19.02)         &    (-16.10)         &    (-21.81)         &    (-21.47)         \\
\hline
N           &      146482         &      146482         &      146482         &      146482         \\
$Adjusted R^2$        &       0.158         &       0.158         &       0.305         &       0.303         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{longtable}
\label{Tabelle}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't put the longtable inside a table environment.

Comment: if i do that its not compiling "undefined control sequence".

Comment: read the documentation of longtable. It tells you how to use it and how to add a \caption.

Comment: Thanks alot you really helped me, great help, tremendous guy, best forum ever! Never thought myself of deleting the table environment or reading the manual.

Comment: @McHack - Why the sexist language? (Ulrike is woman...)

Comment: sorry i corrected it :Thanks alot you really helped me, great help, tremendous girl, best forum ever! Never thought myself of deleting the table environment or reading the manual.